# SMS paging sends a new number every time

Tags: scheduled-task, alerts, paging

We have set up SQL Server to send out alerts when jobs fail.  Text messages are sent to `1234567890@txt.ATT.Net`, and they show up on our phones.

However, the alerts come in from a weird 9-digit number like `(201)100-218`, `(201)100-219`,  `(201)100-220`.. notice the increment?

I want have a special ringtone to alert me, but I cannot do that because it sends a new phone number every time, and I cannot add a contact for that.

Of course, AT&T isn't going to change their email-to-SMS policy just for me.

What do you Sys Admins / DBAs do about alerts and special ringtones in cases like this?  Are there alternatives that would send alerts / notifications from a single number?

Is there a way of working around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You sign up for an account with something like Twilio, Clickatell, etc, and use their APIs for sending messages.

As you are finding out, carriers' email-to-SMS gateways are not meant to be used for anything critical or production-quality. With the advent of smartphone push notifications, my forecast I that these email-to-SMS services will be gone within a few years.